# Does the glibc getaddrinfo vulnerability affect Windows systems?

Tags: vulnerability, glibc

Recently Google discovered the ["glibc getaddrinfo" vulnerability (CVE-2015-7547)](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/cve-2015-7547-glibc-getaddrinfo-stack.html).

Does this vulnerability affect Windows systems at all? I think it might because I'm not sure that glibc is a Linux-only piece of software. It might be able to be part of a Windows software or it might run emulated on Windows (Cygwin?!). I have searched for "glibc windows" but the search results are inconclusive to me.

Is this concern valid at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concern is largely unfounded as the glibc (GNU C library) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library is utilized on the *nix platforms and is not part of the native Windows environment.

If you are running Cywin or any other Linux emulator, you might want to go ahead, patch and reboot

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a vulnerable version of glibc in windows, then yes. It is vulnerable. Of course glibc is not commonly used in the windows environment.